# How to compare s shaped curves?

Tags: distributions, correlation

I have two variables A and B that can take positive values, they are two different counters of "votes" for a group of about 400 individuals. My hypothesis is that these two kind of votes are related with some degree of direct proportionality: if a subject takes x votes for vote type A (A = x), he will likely take y votes for vote type B (B = y); if another subject takes xx votes for vote type A with xx > x, he will likely take yy votes for vote type B with yy > y. Etc.

So now I have two series of votes distributed in an exponential-like curve: it means that there is a lot of people with few votes and very few people with a lot of votes (both for A and B type of vote). In order to study the relationship between the two types of vote I tried to do a linear regression of the log of the exponential curves and look at the correlation value, which is around 0,7.

The problem is that the log of the exponential curve has not a linear shape, it has a S shape, visually similar to a logit (but with a central section almost linear). Is it wrong to do linear regression in a case like this? How else can I test the correlation? Is there some other type of test I can do?

(as you can guess I'm a total beginner in statistics)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem with Pearson correlation usage from your description. You may try rank order correlations such as Spearman and Kendall tau.

Comment: Thanks Aksakal for the suggestions. I tried Spearman too, but not Kendall tau.